# Using if statement with is(':visible')

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have this piece of code, which when the submit button on the contact form is pressed, the "moveon" button appears:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        $("#moveon").css({'display':'block'});
    });
});
```

When the contact form is submitted, it displays a div called "success_page" and what I would like is for the "moveon" button to only dispay when the "success_page" div is visible. (i.e the form was submitted properly.) I'm thinking it requires some kind of if statement using the is(':visible') function however I'm new to coding and jquery and don't know the syntax required to make this happen.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you want to show the moveon button at the same time as the success_page div, why not do both at the same time?

Comment: @cadrell0 I think thats what I'm trying to do. I'm using a page slider script, which works by adding trigger classes to links, to slide to the next page. When I add these classes to a link or button outside of my index file it doesn't register them, and although I'm sure there is a way to make it work, It's a little out of my skill level I think.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. The function is `is`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        if ( $("#success_page").is(":visible") ){
            $("#moveon").css({'display':'block'});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there a possibility that because the div "success_page" is in the contact.php file, the function is not registering that it is visible?

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you could also do this:

```
if ( $("#success_page:visible").length > 0 ){
    $("#moveon").css({'display':'block'});
}
```